Force Git to use customized .vimrc
After putting core.editor=vim to git's config is there a way to force git to launch vim with .vimrc other than $HOME/.vimrc? I mean I would like to have different settings for my day-to-day vim (which is $HOME/.vimrc) and other one for git tasks.
One can create aliases for all git commands (like git commit, git difftool) invoking  vim. These aliases would, for example, launch external bash script that prepares everything, but it's not the way I would like to go for. Something I have in mind is:

Putting path to custom vimrc into ~/.gitconfig
Setting some variable similar to SSH OPTIONS

Is there something like that?

Have you tried something like core.editor="vim -u path/to/different_vimrc" ?

I did not mention it in question - but it did not work for me. I was wondering if there is any option like core.editor_options or anything similiar..
